Flutter News Toolkit does not display html table
I was following example for "The Flutter News Toolkit" by "Very Good Ventures", and Google News Initiative NewsToolKit and added a HtmlBlock with a table, but it does not display the table.
NewsItem(
    post: PostSmallBlock(

      id: '499305f6-5096-4051-afda-824dcfc7df20',
      category: PostCategory.technology,
      author: 'Hollister',
      publishedAt: DateTime(2024, 4, 19),
      title: 'html'          ,
      action: const NavigateToArticleAction(
        articleId: '499305f6-5096-4051-afda-824dcfc7df20',
      ),
    ),
    content: [
      const HtmlBlock(content: '<p><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Years Of Service</th></tr><tr><td>Buddy</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>CoCo</td><td>20</td></tr></table></p>'),
      const HtmlBlock(content: '<p>hello 123 world</p>'),
    ],
    contentPreview: [
      ArticleIntroductionBlock(
          category: PostCategory.technology,
          author: 'Hollister',
          publishedAt: DateTime(2024, 4, 19),
          title: 'html'
      ),
      const TextLeadParagraphBlock(
        text:   'html',
      ),
    ],
    url: Uri.parse(
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/',
    ),
  ),


When the app is run the link is shown, but when clicked, content page does not show html portion it.


